# What is a branch point?

Tags: complex-analysis, branch-cuts, branch-points, multivalued-functions

I am really struggling with the concept of a "branch point". I understand that, for example, if we take the $\log$ function, by going around $2\pi$ we arrive at a different value, so therefore it is a multivalued function. However, surely this argument holds for all points in the complex plane, so I don't really understand how $z=0$ is the ONLY branch point.

Additionally, the course I am revising for needs no Riemann surfaces or knowledge of that area of mathematics, just what a branch point is and how to find it.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: A branch point is  a common point to all branch cuts of your function. If you take the logarithm function the branch point is $z = 0$.

Comment: the searched answer can be found here http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BranchPoint.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A branch point of a "multi-valued function" $f$ is a point $z$ with this property: there does *not* exist an open neighbourhood $U$ of $z$ on which $f$ has a single-valued branch.

In the case of $\log$, the only branch point is $0$: indeed, if $z \ne 0$, we could take 
$$U = \{ w \in \mathbb{C} : \lvert w - z \rvert < \lvert z \rvert \}$$
and define a single-valued branch of $\log$ on $U$. If you want to think in terms of paths, the point is that the value of $\log$ cannot jump if the path does not wind around $0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am still unsure as to how 0 is the only branch point, for example if we choose z=1 and go around the circle, we do not return to z=1, so therefore why is z=1 not a branch point?

Comment: That is because the circle is too big and does in fact wind around $0$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Based on your definition of neighborhood $U$, since the circle will always include $z=0$, then aren't you saying that $log(0)$ is a single-valued branch? and if not, then what is a "single-valued branch"?

Comment: The definition in this 2015 answer disagrees with standard usage for algebraic functions.  Under the usual definition, $\sqrt{1-\sqrt{z}}$ has a branch point at $z=1$, but there is a single-valued branch of $\sqrt{z}$ in a neighborhood of $z=1$ taking the value $-1$ at $z=1$, and hence a single-valued branch of  $\sqrt{1-\sqrt{z}}$ in a neighborhood of $z=1$ taking the value $\sqrt{2}$ at $z=1$.  Another way to say it: the Riemann surface of this function is ramified at some but not all of the points above $z=1$; that's enough to make $1$ a branch point.